# Error in FD package in R: Species labels in 'x' and 'a' need to be identical and ordered alphabetically (or simply in the same order)

Tags: r

I saw that others had this problem before but the solutions they found didn't work for me so far unfortunately.

I am trying to find my way around the FD package and to reproduce some examples it gives with my own data. I read "How to make a great R reproducible example" and hope to do it right.

Here is a short version of my data:

```
dput(wood_trait[1:4,1:4])
structure(list(family = c("Sapindaceae", "Sapindaceae", "Sapindaceae", 
"Sapindaceae"), growth = c("T", "T", "T", "T"), pollsyn = c("entomophilous", 
"both", "entomophilous", "entomophilous"), beepoll = c(" 1", 
" 1", NA, " 1")), row.names = c("Acercampestre", "Acernegundo", 
"Acerpalmatum", "Acerplatanoides"), class = "data.frame")
```

```
dput(wood_abun[,1:4])
structure(c(" 0", " 0", " 0", "11", " 0", " 0", " 1", " 0", " 0", 
" 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 2", " 0", " 3", " 0", " 1", " 0", 
" 0", " 1", "13", " 0", " 1", " 1", "10", " 0", " 0", " 1", " 6", 
" 0", " 1", " 0", " 0", " 2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", " 0", 
" 0", " 0", " 0", " 4", " 6", " 0", " 0", "53", " 0", " 4", " 6", 
" 0", " 2", " 0", " 1", " 0", " 2"), .Dim = c(18L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("AllmendeKontor", "GASFK", "GASTS", "GartenderBegegnung", 
    "Himmelbeet", "Inselgarten", "Fischerstrasse", "Klunker", 
    "PeaceofLand", "VatNeuGruenstr", "Prinzessin", "RoteBeete", 
    "Schalotten", "BurbacherWeg", "SpielFeld", "Wachsenlassen", 
    "Vollguter", "Wieckerstrasse"), c("Acercampestre", "Acernegundo", 
    "Acerpalmatum", "Acerplatanoides")))
```

When running:

```
exwood2 <- functcomp(wood_trait, wood_abun)
```

I get the following error message:

*Species labels in 'x' and 'a' need to be identical and ordered alphabetically (or simply in the same order).*

I have checked multiple times with excel that the species labels are identical. I am a bit afraid that the problem lies somewhere else in the data than in the subset I am posting here.. But I am not sure how to find it. Also, doesn't this

```
setdiff(attr(wood_trait, 'Labels'), colnames(wood_abun))
```

NULL

suggest that there is no difference between the rownames and column names? But:

```
identical(row.names(wood_trait), colnames(wood_abun))
```

[1] FALSE

I would very much appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out! I created subsets of only a few rows/columns at a time and compared them using identical() as described above. I finally managed to find where the error was, found it in excel and changed it and now it works.

The data was indeed the same in both excel sheets, but it had a `-` sign in it and taking it out solved the problem.